# Multiple distinct counts with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue creating most efficient query for multiple distinct counts of a column with different where clauses. My MYSQL table looks like this:

```
id    client_id    result       timestamp
---------------------------------------------------
 1    1234566      escalated    2014-01-02 00:00:00
 2    1233344      approved     2014-02-03 00:00:00
 3    1234566      escalated    2014-01-02 01:00:00
```

What I am trying to achieve is to build the following data in the return:

Total number of unique client IDs processed from the beginning of time.

Total number of unique client IDs processed escalated from the beginning of time.

Total number of unique client IDs processed approved from the beginning of time.

Count of unique client IDs approved within specified timeframe using between statement on timestamp.

Count of unique client IDs escalated within specified timeframe using between statement on timestamp.

I have thought about running multiple selects, but I think it would be a waste of resources, and possibly if this could be done with a single query it would the best way to handle it, unfortunately my experience is lacking in this area. What I would like would the return to simple contain an alias and the count.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation, something like:

```
select count(distinct ClientId) as NumClients,
       count(distinct case when result = 'Approved' then ClientId end) as NumApproved,
       count(distinct case when result = 'Escalated' then ClientId end) as NumEscalated,
       count(distinct case when result = 'Approved' and timestamp between @Time1 and @Time2 
                           then ClientId end) as NumApproved,
       count(distinct case when result = 'Escalated' and timestamp between @Time1 and @Time2
                           then ClientId end) as NumEscalated,
from table t;
```